# Grails NoClassDefFoundError BuildableCriteria in during run test

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I have a project on grails 2.3.9, i have upgraded this project into grails 2.5.6, java 8 
I have successfully upgraded this, but getting error in testcases(grails test-app)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.TestGormEnhancer.getStaticApi(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:188)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.addStaticMethods(GormEnhancer.groovy:118)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.enhance(GormEnhancer.groovy:112)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.enhance(GormEnhancer.groovy:95)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:99)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$1$2.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:49)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$3$4.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:76)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.ClassRuleInterceptor.intercept(ClassRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.BuildableCriteria
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:179)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I also added datastore-test-support dependency but getting same issue:
**test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"**
It was working fine with grails 2.3.9

please help here

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.BuildableCriteria` interface is contained in `grails-datastore-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar` which by default would be pulled into a Grails 2.5.6 as a transitive dependency of the `org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.10` plugin.  I would verify that you have expressed a dependency on that in your `BuildConfig.groovy`.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // ...
    plugins {
        // ...
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10"
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The above solution assumes you are using Hibernate of course.  If you are using any other GORM implementation, which plugin you pull in would depend on which implementation you are using.